# DataContractJsonSerializer - share an object instance for the whole graph?

Tags: c#, serialization

I am using a `DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize an object graph. When I construct the objects, each receives a reference to an instance of a utility object (it's a factory, for creating instances of subclasses of an abstract contract class) - which works great until the graph is serialized and then deserialized again, whereupon the objects no longer have a reference to the utility object any more. I need this reference. How would you recommend I implement this (singletons don't work because separate graphs need their own instance of the object)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is with a [data contract surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064(v=vs.110).aspx).  Using surrogates, you can replace your "real" factory with a dummy stub during serialization.  Then, during deserialization, replace the dummy with the desired factory.

Thus, if your classes look something like:

```
public abstract class FactoryBase
{
}

public class Factory : FactoryBase
{
}

public interface IHasFactory
{
    FactoryBase Factory { get; }
}

[DataContract]
public abstract class HasFactoryBase : IHasFactory
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    FactoryBase factory;

    public FactoryBase Factory { get { return factory; } }

    public HasFactoryBase(FactoryBase factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Foo : HasFactoryBase
{
    public Foo(FactoryBase factory)
        : base(factory)
    {
        this.Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Bar : HasFactoryBase
{
    public Bar(FactoryBase factory) : base(factory) { }
}
```

You define an [`IDataContractSurrogate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.aspx) to replace all occurrences of `FactoryBase` with a surrogate as follows:

```
public class FactorySurrogateSelector : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    [DataContract]
    class FactorySurrogate
    {
    }

    readonly FactoryBase factory;

    public FactorySurrogateSelector(FactoryBase factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    #region IDataContractSurrogate Members

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        if (typeof(FactoryBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            return typeof(FactorySurrogate);
        return type;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj is FactorySurrogate)
            return factory;
        return obj;
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj is FactoryBase)
        {
            return new FactorySurrogate();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, serialize and deserialize as follows:

```
var factory = new Factory();
var test = new Foo(factory)
{
    Bars = { new Bar(factory) },
};

var surrogate = new FactorySurrogateSelector(factory);
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(test.GetType(), Enumerable.Empty<Type>(), int.MaxValue, false, surrogate, false);

byte[] json;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, test);
    json = stream.ToArray();
}

Foo test2;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(json))
{
    test2 = (Foo)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}

if (test2.Factory != test.Factory)
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

Notice that the desired factory was passed directly into the constructor of the `FactorySurrogateSelector`, then eventually set inside each type that contains instances of the factory type.

The resulting JSON will look like:

```
{
  "factory": {},
  "Bars": [
    {
      "factory": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Some qualifications:

- Your factory must inherit from some common base class, here `FactoryBase`.  The data contract serializers will *never* serialize an interface member, e.g. `IFactory factory` where `IFactory` is your factory interface, even when there is an applicable surrogate.
- The empty `"factory": {}` objects must appear in the JSON in order for the surrogate to inject the correct "real" factory value during deserialization.  Hence the `[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish is to introduce a [thread static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) or [thread local](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh(v=vs.110).aspx) factory object, then populate your classes with it using an [`[OnDeserializing]` callback](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/09/05/wcf-extensibility-serialization-callbacks/).

Thus, if you define your types as follows:

```
public interface IFactory
{
}

public class Factory : IFactory
{
}

public interface IHasFactory
{
    IFactory Factory { get; }
}

[DataContract]
public abstract class HasFactoryBase : IHasFactory
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static IFactory deserializedFactory;

    static IFactory DeserializedFactory
    {
        get
        {
            return deserializedFactory;
        }
        set
        {
            deserializedFactory = value;
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable SetDeserializedFactory(IFactory factory)
    {
        return new PushValue<IFactory>(factory, () => DeserializedFactory, val => DeserializedFactory = val);
    }

    IFactory factory;

    public IFactory Factory { get { return factory; } }

    public HasFactoryBase(IFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    [OnDeserializing]
    void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.factory = DeserializedFactory;
    }
}

public struct PushValue<T> : IDisposable
{
    Action<T> setValue;
    T oldValue;

    public PushValue(T value, Func<T> getValue, Action<T> setValue)
    {
        if (getValue == null || setValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.setValue = setValue;
        this.oldValue = getValue();
        setValue(value);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    // By using a disposable struct we avoid the overhead of allocating and freeing an instance of a finalizable class.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (setValue != null)
            setValue(oldValue);
    }

    #endregion
}

[DataContract]
public class Foo : HasFactoryBase
{
    public Foo(IFactory factory)
        : base(factory)
    {
        this.Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Bar : HasFactoryBase
{
    public Bar(IFactory factory) : base(factory) { }
}
```

You can serialize and deserialize as follows:

```
var factory = new Factory();
var test = new Foo(factory)
{
    Bars = { new Bar(factory) },
};

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(test.GetType());

byte [] json;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, test);
    json = stream.ToArray();
}

Foo test2;
using (HasFactoryBase.SetDeserializedFactory(factory))
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(json))
{
    test2 = (Foo)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}

if (test2.Factory != test.Factory)
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

And the JSON will look like:

```
{
  "Bars": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

Some notes:

- The factory object does not appear at all in the JSON.
- The factory objects no longer need to inherit from some abstract base class, they can simply implement a common `IFactory` interface.