# How to serialize a class that may only have unique instances

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class that can only have unique instances as below. This makes reference equality sufficient to equate objects.

While serialization is simple, deserialization is a bit tricky as one cannot assign to `this` as i have done below. How do i deserialize objects if still want to maintain only unique instances of the class?

```
public sealed class MyClass :
    ISerializable,
    IXmlSerializable
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, MyClass> Cache;

    static MyClass() { /* build cache, use private constructor */ }

    private MyClass(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public static MyClass Parse(string from)
        => Cache[from];

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() => null;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        this = Parse(reader.ReadContentAsString());
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
        => this = Parse(info.GetString(nameof(this.Name)));

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: If you're able to change your class code, I would highly suggest to replace your class by three different ones; one for serialization/deserialization, one for caching, and another one for the class that you need to cache. Your class here makes different responsibilities which makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the way to deal with this issue is, during object graph serialization, to replace the singleton(s) using a [serialization surrogate mechanism](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/09/13/wcf-extensibility-serialization-surrogates/), wherein the singleton is replaced with a [Data Transfer Object (DTO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that contains nothing other than an identifier for the singleton.  Then, later, as the graph is being deserialized, the DTO is initially deserialized, then replaced with the corresponding singleton via a lookup.

For instance, if your `MyClass` looks as follows:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, MyClass> Cache;

    static MyClass()
    {
        Cache = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>()
        {
            { "one", new MyClass("one") { OtherRuntimeData = "other runtime data 1" } },
            { "two", new MyClass("two") { OtherRuntimeData = "other runtime data 2" } },
        };
    }

    // XmlSerializer required parameterless constructor.
    private MyClass() => throw new NotImplementedException();

    private MyClass(string name) => this.Name = name;

    public string Name { get; }

    public string OtherRuntimeData { get; set; }

    public static MyClass Parse(string from) => Cache[from];

    public static IEnumerable<MyClass> Instances => Cache.Values;
}
```

Then a DTO containing only the `Name` would look like:

```
public sealed class MyClassDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MyClassDTO(MyClass obj) => obj == null ? null : new MyClassDTO { Name = obj.Name };

    public static implicit operator MyClass(MyClassDTO dto) => dto == null ? null : MyClass.Parse(dto.Name);
}
```

Notice the [implicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) for converting between the DTO and the original?  That will make it easier to inject the surrogate into the serialization graph.

Unfortunately, however, there is no standard way to implement injection of a serialization surrogate DTO in all of the commonly used .Net serializers.  Each has its own separate mechanism (or no mechanism at all).  To break them down:

- The data contract serializers support replacement with a surrogate via the [`IDataContractSurrogate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates) interface, as shown e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730192/3744182) to [DataContractJsonSerializer - share an object instance for the whole graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40728704/3744182) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18957739/3744182) to [How to serialize / deserialize immutable list type in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18955441/3744182).
- The data contract serializers also support the [`IObjectReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iobjectreference.aspx) interface as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1990054/3744182) to [C# DataContract Serialization, how to deserialize to already existing instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1941580/3744182).
- But unfortunately `XmlSerializer` has no convenient support for injection of DTOs via a surrogate mechanism.  The closest one can come is the trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322461/3744182) to [Most elegant XML serialization of Color structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3280362/3744182), which involves setting the [`XmlElementAttribute.Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.type.aspx) to the DTO type for every property that refers to your singleton type, for instance as follows:

  ```
  public class RootObject
  {
      // Technique taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280362/most-elegant-xml-serialization-of-color-structure
      [XmlElement(Type=typeof(MyClassDTO))]
      public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  Sample .Net fiddle showing this in action here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R07NiW.   Note this only works because of the implicit operator between the singleton and its DTO that we defined previously.
- When serializing via Json.NET, the singleton can be replaced with its DTO inside a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).
- [protobuf.net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) supports replacement with surrogates via `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(OriginalType), false) .SetSurrogate(typeof(SurrogateType))` as shown in [Can I serialize arbitrary types with protobuf-net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7046506/3744182), [No serializer defined for type: System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33495897/3744182), or the article [Protobuf-net: the unofficial manual](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642677/Protobuf-net-the-unofficial-manual#forms).
- Finally, if you are using `BinaryFormatter` (which I do not recommend for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/703073/3744182)), use of the [`SurrogateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.surrogateselector.aspx) mechanism, which resembles the data contract surrogate replacement mechanism, is supported as is shown in [Customized Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42798279).

  `SerializationInfo.SetType()` combined with `IObjectReference` is also supported, as is shown in [this documentation example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.settype.aspx#Examples).